# How to stop divs from stacking over each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of divs that contain two internal divs. The paragraphs within one of these internal divs are overlapping the ones below it. Everything seems to be lining up with the img in the other internal div. See image: [image: Visual of output]

Here is the code that I am working with HTML, this snippet is repeat with no changes in tags or css:

```css
    .research_area {
      @include size(mdu) {
      }
      @include size(lgu) {
        padding: 0px 80px;
      }
      @include size(xlu) {
        padding: 0px 180px;
      }
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    
    .research_area .research_left {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .research_area .research_right {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      h4 {
        margin-top: 1px;
      }
      p {
        max-width: 680px;
        font-size: 90%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <div class="research_area clearfix">
        <div class="research_left">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O https://placeholder.com/" />
        </div>
      <div class="research_right">
        <h4><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O https://placeholder.com/" /></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Hard to replicate the issue without a fully reproducible example to work with, but I suspect `position: absolute;` is the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am sure I am doing many things wrong, thanks for the link I will definitely check it out!

Comment: @abney317 Sorry, I am used to posting in the Rails area where just snippets seem to be all that is needed. I removed absolute position and that fixed my paragraphs overlapped. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `position: absolute;` to display your text inline with the image, try using CSS's [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout. Instead of forcing an element to appear in a certain spot regardless of the other content in the layout (causing the overflow issue), `flex` will display your elements fluidly, depending on the content.

See example below:

```css
.research_area {
  display: flex;
}

.research_area .research_left {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.research_area .research_right h4 {
  margin-top: 1px
}

.research_area .research_right p {
  max-width: 680px;
  font-size: 90%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="research_area clearfix">
    <div class="research_left">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    </div>
  <div class="research_right">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="research_area clearfix">
    <div class="research_left">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    </div>
  <div class="research_right">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="research_area clearfix">
    <div class="research_left">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    </div>
  <div class="research_right">
    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was just looking at the flexbox but thanks to you I can see it in action and understand that it is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!